# Бот для игры в 'Слова' для telegram бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Возможно ли сделать телеграм бота для игры в слова на языке программирования python
(Пользователь пишет слово, а бот придумывает слово на последнюю букву предыдущего. Например:
Пользователь: машин**А**
Бот: **А**рбу**З**
Пользователь: **З**ебр**А**
И так далее)
если да, то подскажите библиотеку

Comment: Вам стоит уточнить для чего именно Вы желаете сделать бота? `Телеграм/Дискорд` или просто исполняемый скрипт в `python` (так как каждая реализация имеет свои нюансы). В любом случае, самый простой и минимально-исполняемый код для выполнения этой задачи Вы можете сделать просто используя модуль `random` и списком заранее сформированных слов, где поиск выполняется по `last_letter = word[-1]`. Во всяком случае, Вам нужно уточнить вопрос и добавить свое минимальное решение, чтобы Вам смогли корректно оказать поддержку.

Comment: Для телеграмм бота, а можно как то сделать так что бы бот сам слова придумывал?

Comment: Так и тем более тогда бот будет выводить случайное слово, а мне надо что бы это слово начиналось с быквы предедущего

Comment: Чтобы он сам слова придумывал, можете имплементировать нейросети, но тогда Вам придется их заранее обучить или постараться найти где-то заранее обученные. По второму комментарию, там же указано про `last_letter`, бот будет выводить случайное слово и списка, которое начинается на последнюю букву.  Для этого будет совершаться проверка в этом списке. Все же не так просто :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сделал для Вас условно рабочий код с использованием нейронной сети от `OPEN AI (модель GPT2 - text-davinci-002)`. Это Вам для затравки, читайте документацию, изучайте, развивайте и у Вас все получится. Здесь не прописано множество ограничений, таких как проверка того, чтобы пользователь вводил корректный ответ с учетом последнего слова бота, исключения на буквы `"ь, ы"` ну и прочих, возможно нестандартных ответов бота, которые нужно протестировать, но которые обязательно будут.

Успехов Вам в изучении.

**Код:**

```python
import telebot
import openai

bot = telebot.TeleBot("{Ваш TELEGRAM TOKEN}") # Регистрируется через BOT FATHER в TELEGRAM

openai.api_key = "{Ваш OPEN AI API KEY}" # Нужно быть зарегистированым в OPEN AI и получить токен.


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def game(message):
    # Получение последней буквы слова пользователя
    last_letter = message.text[-1].lower()
    # Получение списка слов из OpenAI GPT-2 модели
    prompt = f"Give me a word that starts with {last_letter}"
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        engine="text-davinci-002",
        prompt=prompt,
        max_tokens=60,
        n=1,
        stop=None,
        temperature=0.5,
    )
    generated_word = response.choices[0].text.strip()

    # Если полученное слово не пустое и начинается с правильной буквы, отправляем его пользователю, иначе выполняем else
    if generated_word and generated_word[0].lower() == last_letter:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, generated_word)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "К сожалению, я не знаю слов на букву " + last_letter)

bot.polling()
```

**Фрагмент отработки данного кода:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Дополненный код с реализацией механизма проверки того, что пользователь пишет следующее слово с нужной буквы:**

```python
import telebot
import openai

bot = telebot.TeleBot("{Ваш TELEGRAM TOKEN}") # Регистрируется через BOT FATHER в TELEGRAM


openai.api_key = "{Ваш OPEN AI API KEY}" # Нужно быть зарегистированым в OPEN AI и получить токен.

last_letter = None


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def game(message):
    global last_letter  # Объявляем, что будем использовать глобальную переменную

    # Если last_letter пустая, значит это первый ход игры, и нужно получить первое слово от пользователя
    if last_letter is None:
        last_letter = message.text[-1].lower()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Начнем игру! Введите слово, которое начинается с буквы " + last_letter)
    else:
        first_letter = message.text[0].lower()
        if first_letter != last_letter:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                             "К сожалению, вы ввели неверное слово. Введите слово, которое начинается с буквы " + last_letter)
        else:
            last_letter = message.text[-1].lower()
            prompt = f"Give me a word that starts with {last_letter}"
            response = openai.Completion.create(
                engine="text-davinci-002",
                prompt=prompt,
                max_tokens=60,
                n=1,
                stop=None,
                temperature=0.5,
            )
            generated_word = response.choices[0].text.strip()
            if generated_word and generated_word[0].lower() == last_letter:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, generated_word)
                last_letter = generated_word[-1].lower()
            else:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "К сожалению, я не знаю слов на букву " + last_letter)

bot.polling()
```

Comment: Господи, большое тебе спасибо!!! Ты мне очень помог!! Лучший!

Comment: Очень рад, что смог Вам помочь :)

Comment: А можно спросить? А возможно ли сделать так что бы бот проверял что пользователь пишет следующее слово с нужной буквы?

Comment: Нет ничего невозможного, но нужно самому изучать вопрос, который Вас интересует или хотя бы делать попытки к этому. Я дополнил ответ, но в дальнейшем, если возникнут новые вопросы, создавайте для этого новую тему.